# How do you use the Internet and share files in a VirtualBox guest OS?

Tags: virtualbox

I have Ubuntu as the main OS. I installed VirtualBox with a Windows XP guest. How can I share files between the two OSs, and how do I connect to the Internet in the Windows XP guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop your virtual machine. Go to settings (in Virtualbox -> XP guest -> settings) and search for shared folder. Add a folder on your PC like /home/username/Documents/vmshare . And there you go.

Note: You have to install Guest Additions to the guest for this which you can get from Tools-> Guest additions (when your guest is running. It'll mount the VBox iso and install the additions. All you need is a reboot after that.)

Comment: To connect to this share on the guest, visit \\vboxsvr\sharename.

Comment: Yeah true. It should also show up in network shares (or in "The whole network".)

Answer (score 0):

For shared folders;
 see [Shiki's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/144015/how-do-you-use-internet-and-share-files-virtual-box-guest-os/144029#144029).

For internet;
Stop the machine. Go to settings, Network. Check "Enable network adapter".

XP will get an IP from your router and act like an independent machine on your network.